# Compojure or Noir for a UI-less webservice?

Tags: clojure, compojure, noir

If one is planning to create a UI-less web service (receives JSON and/or XML, returns JSON and/or XML), does [Noir](http://webnoir.org/) provide anything useful over and above [Compojure](http://compojure.org/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe Noir makes it a bit simpler to create JSON responses with `noir.response/json`: http://ibdknox.github.com/noir/noir.response-api.html#noir.response/json

On the other hand JSON support in Noir is just a very thin wrapper around clj-json (basically only adds json content-type header) so you can use clj-json directly instead of Noir for this purpose.

Comment: I'd suggest the [Cheshire](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire) library if you're going to add JSON handling yourself.

Comment: I agree with both the answer and the above comment.  I've recently been using Noir to provide a similar API and using it is an absolute dream.  It makes it incredibly easy to define access to your API and cheshire is a wonderful JSON library.  In my case, I was using [congomongo](https://github.com/aboekhoff/congomongo) to connect to a MongoDB instance which returns data in Mongo's native JSON format.

Comment: Also note Chris Granger's response [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clj-noir/INqvBo6oXIA/discussion), and [here](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/clj-noir/11ahzz6n7q/noir-post-json-data) describing how to use it to _receive_ JSON data.

Answer (score 4):

You should choose Compojure, as Noir is now deprecated.

You'll find deprecation notice and recommendations here:
https://github.com/noir-clojure/noir